# How to store ajax values in a queue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to display some data which comes from my db using *jQuery.ajax()* (i.e. each one contains a title and a description)  and I want this process to be done on a regular basis, say *setInterval(func, 5000)*.

Now what I actually need is a js container (an array, a variable, whatever) in which I can store these items to and using another function, I want them to be displayed every 2 seconds.

So, in other words:

- We have to have two functions and a container, if you will. The ajax function is fired every 5 seconds and appends its data (if any) into the container (a queue).
- On the other hand, the second function displays the content of our container every 2 seconds and removes the displayed items from the container of course.

How can I implement this?

Comment: So you want to know how to store the variables that come from the AJAX request?

Comment: Sounds like you want something like a queue. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not only one value, it has to be available in somewhere like a variable in js and I want to display them one by one (every x seconds) -- regardless of what arrives through the ajax

Comment: @FelixKling: that's right. I tried to do it using an array but I couldn't because I had to pass some helper values on every call. I want to know what the best practice is, and preferably an example would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What are those helper values? And what's the reason not to append data as soon as first function receives it?

Comment: As I couldn't implement it first, I tried passing the row_number (item number) to know and sync what the last received item is, then it started to become more complex as I didn't know a better approach to do so. And the fact is the real project is a tad more complex and I simplified it in my question. (the user can actually remove/cancel an entry before it shows up!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var queue = [];

function ajaxCall() {
  $.when($.ajax(...)).done(function(data) {
     ///assuming your data json's outermost structure is an array
     while(data[0]) {
        queue.push(data.shift());
     }
  })
}

function publisher() {
   var item = queue.shift();
   if(item) {
      //do your gubbins here
   }
}

setInterval(ajaxCall,5000);

setInterval(publisher, 2000);
```

Comment: Your answer made me look up Deferred Object in jQuery. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, they're not strictly necessary for this example, but I'm trying to get into the habit of using the new syntax all the time because sometimes it's incredibly useful.

Comment: Thanks, you killed two birds with one stone ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using an Array. It can store a string, an object...

Take a look at this great blog [post](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/).

If you need queue, this [post](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/queues/) may help you....

Comment: I really used that article on js associative arrays, thank you

Answer (score 0):

first, set up a container like this one :

```
<div id="container">
 <ul>
 </ul>
</div>
```

then, in your .js :

```
//step 1. define global Array to hold the values
$(document).ready(function(){
  var items = new Array();

  //step 3. call the ajax every 5 second
  var updateInterval = setInterval(function() {
    get_the_data();
  //don't forget to empty the array
        items = [];

   }, 5000);

  //step 4. so now, with the data got refresh every 5 second, you just have to append this data into container every 2 second. use the .html method
 //logically, in first two times invoke to this method (4 seconds) the container would get same data from array, but in third invocation (at 6 seconds) the container get the fresh one, and so on...
  var insertToContainer = setInterval(function() {
    for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
      $('#container ul').html('<li>' + items[i] + '</li>')                  
   }                
    }, 2000);

});

//step 2. set up your ajax call
function get_the_data()
{
  $.ajax({
     //set your ajax code here...
     success:function(data){
        //on success put the data into the global array
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
             items.push(data[i]);
        }
     }
  });
}
```

I hope this would work for your project. Cheers :-)
PS: frankly speaking, I don't know why you wanted such implementation (i mean, 2 different update functions with different interval value), the more simple way is using just one invocation to the ajax call every 2 seconds as long as display it in container using .html , but it's just my opinion, It should be more complex logic behind your app. :-)

Comment: Thanks under5hell, based on your simple and thorough explanations I could solve the whole thing. I appreciate it